# What is meant by half duplex in the context of computer networking?

Tags: wireless-networking

"Using say http://www.speedtest.net/ to verify speed  You can generally expect only 50% of the channel speed for DL and less for UL, as it is a half duplex link."

what is meant by saying half duplex. I know the channel is full duplex.is there any more detail

Answer (score 0):

Half duplex means that the channel can only be used in one direction(down or up) at a given time.  It is often referred to as a shared channel.  If the channel is full duplex you can ignore the comment about half duplex.  A channel can only be half or full, but a full duplex can be configured to operate at half duplex though it degrades performance.

Wikipedia has more details if you are interested: [Wikipedia Half Duplex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplex_%28telecommunications%29#Half-duplex)

Answer (score 0):

In the radio world there are 3 basic types of communications. Simplex, Half Duplex, and Full Duplex.

Simplex: One frequency used for transmitting and receiving with the communication parties transmitting by taking turns.

Half Duplex: Where the system like a repeater transmits on one frequency and receives on another and like Simplex only one party can communicate at one time.

Full Duplex: Like a Cellular phone where you have 2 frequencies for transmitting and receiving simultaneously and both parties can communicate interactively.